# about compress of webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

There's something about angular:
When the code is online
You can package it as a js, so that you can reduce the number of HTTP requests;
Now I'm packing all the files into a bundle. Js, but loading the site takes 20 seconds
How can I deal with it?
- note: the packaging technology USES webpack

Comment: Did you build it with the -prod flag?

Comment: These links are quite good for increasing the performance.
[Link 1](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/),
[Link2](http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/17/angular-in-production/)

Answer (score 0):

After doing your *ng build -prod* you can compress your js files using uglifyjs.

- Install it globally:

> npm install uglify-js -g

- Compress your js files. (And option would be compress them one by one)

> uglifyjs main.bundle.js -c toplevel,sequences=false -o
>   main.bundle.min.js
>
> uglifyjs inline.bundle.js -c
>   toplevel,sequences=false -o inline.bundle.min.js
>
> uglifyjs
>   polyfills.bundle.js -c toplevel,sequences=false -o
>   polyfills.bundle.min.js
>
> uglifyjs vendor.bundle.js -c
>   toplevel,sequences=false -o vendor.bundle.min.js
>
> uglifyjs
>   styles.bundle.js -c toplevel,sequences=false -o styles.bundle.min.js

- Change index.html to refer to .min.js

**NOTE: I would recomend to create a npm script for doing this automatically once you have try it. To do it change your package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "compress": "sh compress.sh"
  },
```

And then run it with -> *npm run-script compress*

Comment: Since he is using webpack he can use uglifyjs-webpack-plugin for the production build. Which for webpack 1 it's already built-in on webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin. For webpack 2 you have to install it asside and require it.

Comment: You are right @Ignasi. New version of angular is providing it https://angular.io/guide/webpack#plugins